# Most succinct way of prepopulating the author in django 1.2 admin?

Tags: django, django-admin

A previous answer points to http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/CookBookNewformsAdminAndUser

I'm wondering if it's really necessary to define both `save_model` and `save_formset` methods in Django 1.2 in order to prepopulate the author?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with inlines you need to override `save_formset` for you inline models as well, for working with the normal admin `save_model` should be sufficent!